# Javascript: how to access anonymous object within object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string generated by php's json_encode() that looks like this:

```
[ { "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3":"value3"
  },
  { "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3":"value3"
  } ]
```

I use Javascript function to convert the string to Javascript object:

```
var jsonObj=JSON.parse(string);
```

How do I access the data inside since the inner objects have no names? I tried something like:

```
alert(jsonObj.firstChild.key1);
```

It gives me "undefined". Why is that so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `alert(jsonObj[0].key1)`